# Composition Series Equivalent Conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let G be a group. Show that $G$ has a composition series iff $G$ satisfies the following two conditions.
>
> (i) If $G=G_1\triangleright G_2 \dots$ then there is an $n$ such that $G_n=G_{n+1}=\dots$.
>
> (ii) If $H$ is a term of a normal series of $G$ and $H_1 \subset H_2 \subset \dots $ is an ascending sequence of normal subgroups of $H$, then there exists an $m$ such that $H_m=H_{m+1}=\dots.$

To show that (i) and (ii) imply G has a composition series I want to start with a normal chain of $G$, $G=G=G_1\triangleright G_2 \dots$, where we require that $G_i\neq G_{i+1}$. This has to terminate at say $n$. Then without loss of generality we can say that $G_n=\{e\}$.

Look at $G_k\triangleright G_{k+1}$ for $k=1,2,\dots,n-1$. If $G_k/G_{k+1}$ is simple we are fine. If not we somehow want to build a normal series between $G_k$ and $G_{k+1}$ where each factor is simple.

I am sort of stuck at this step. So I could use help on this.

I also have no idea how to show that if $G$ has a composition series that $G$ satisfies (i) and (ii).

Any help would be great!

Comment: For the direction "(i) + (ii) implies somposition series" I would use the "ascending sequence condition" (ii) to obtain a maximal subgroup (Zorn's Lemma). If you go on you will either have a composition series (then you are done) or an infinite descending sequence (which is forbidden by (i)), thus you are done. For the other implication try induction on the length of a composition series, this should do the trick.

Comment: So if I look at $G_k \triangleright G_{k+1}$ I understand how to get a normal series, $G_{k+1} = H_0 \triangleright H_1 \triangleright \dots \triangleright H_m=G_{k}$. Where $H_0/H_1$ must be simple by the ascending sequence condition, but I have no idea why $H_{k-1}/H_k$ must be simple. Perhaps the way I got the sequence is not correct

Comment: my (i admit sketchy) point was that if you assume that you cannot insert finitely many normal subgroups you obtain an infinite descending sequence (forbidden by (i))

Comment: I think I get it now

Comment: For your induction idea, I'm not really sure what to do. I see why the initial step works, because if the composition series of $G$ is $G\triangleright \{ e\}$ this tells us the $G$ is simple and so (i) and (ii) must hold. However, I'm not sure where to go from there. I thought of maybe modding out by some subgroup.

Comment: Suppose you have a composition series for $G$ of length $k$. Prove that whenever you have a properly descending sequence of normal subgroups then it **must** be of length $t \leq k + 1$. This is the statement which you should prove by induction on $k$ (properties (i) and (ii) follow obviously). This should work by considering different cases ("how the two sequences overlap")